# JS pattern providing function name as string

Tags: javascript, function, design-patterns, anti-patterns

Lately, I've found myself passing function names as string parameters to another function, checking its existence with `typeof`, and calling it if necessary.

I realize as I write this that I could just pass a function reference.

My question is, does the "pass function name as a string" pattern have a common name? And, is it an anti-pattern - should I generally be using references whenever possible?

Comment: Can you show an example of what you are doing? Reason you do not pass references?

Comment: @epascarello - no reason exactly, it's just something I noticed could be done and I've been playing with it.  There's not a use case that forces this behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know that it has a name, but it's definitely an anti-pattern. It's harder, and iirc it's actually going to be worse on memory than just sending the function reference around.

```
function doThisThing() {}
var action = 'doThisThing';
```

You see I actually create two things in memory with a pointer to each.

```
var action = function() {}
```

Here, I created a single item in memory, and `action` is just a pointer to it. Then it's super easy to just

```
if (action) action();
```

or even shorter

```
action && action();
```

It's so so much easier just to pass a reference around. It's just that: a reference. It has little-to-no overhead, and it's way easier.

Comment: Thanks Dan, that makes sense.  To add to the list of anti-pattern-ness, readability (and maintenance) becomes worse as well!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a specifically named pattern, but if you combine this with calling that function via `eval` then I would say that is the anti pattern.

**OK**

```
var obj = {
    foo: function() {},
    bar: function() {},
    execute: function(fnName) {
        this[fnName]();
    }
};

obj.execute("foo");
```

**Bad**

```
var obj = {
    foo: function() {},
    bar: function() {},
    execute: function(fnName) {
        eval("obj." + fnName + "()");
    }
};
```

Comment: Nope, no eval, just calling it as a property of the object, e.g. `obj[fnName]()`.